# How to perform a postgresql WITH auxiliary query in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have this query:

```
WITH words_not AS (
        SELECT keywords.id 
        FROM keywords
        WHERE keywords.keyword = any(array['writing'])
    ),
    actes_not AS (
        SELECT actes_keywords.acte_id
        FROM actes_keywords
        WHERE actes_keywords.keyword_id IN (SELECT id FROM words_not)
    )
    SELECT actes.id, actes.acte_date
    FROM actes
    WHERE actes.id NOT IN (SELECT acte_id FROM actes_not);
```

I would like to "translate" that into rails. However, the documentation doesn't have `.with` among its methods:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Namely these Rails methods are available: `.select` , `.from` and `.where`, so I can do (for example and simplified):

```
Acte.select("actes.id, actes.date_acte").where("actes.id = ?",5)
```

But how can I write the `WITH` auxiliary query that is referred to here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: I think `with` are not in rails, but you can use `find_by_sql` [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If ever this could help:

```
ids_pas_mots = find_by_sql("SELECT \"motclefs\".\"id\" 
     FROM \"motclefs\" 
     WHERE \"motclefs\".\"motcle\" = any(array[#{pas_mes_mots}])"
     )

ids = ids_pas_mots.map{|l| l.id}

ids_pas_actes = find_by_sql("SELECT \"actes_motclefs\".\"acte_id\"
     FROM \"actes_motclefs\"
     WHERE \"actes_motclefs\".\"motclef_id\" = any(array[#{ids}])")

ids_actes = ids_pas_actes.map { |e| e.acte_id  }.join(",")

self.where("\"actes\".\"id\" NOT IN (#{ids_actes})")
```